# removing unknown number of tags from inside a tag

Tags: php, regex

I have these string:

```
$st = '<p><br/></p>';
$st = '<p><br/><br/></p>';
$st = '<p><br/><br/><br/></p>';
```

How can I remove all the line breaks from inside the P tag?
I tried this but didn't work:

```
echo preg_replace('/p>(br\/>)*?<\/p/','p></p',$st);
```

I'm sorry, seem I need to explain. more. This would be inside a larger text and I don't want to remove all the line breaks. Only those which are inside a P tag with unknown number of occurance.

Comment: I've already edited, you don't have to worry. Be careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your REGEX to:

`preg_replace('#p\>(\<br\/\>)*?\<\/p#','p></p',$st)`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I have to scape > < as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are some non-RegEx alternatives,

**Using str_replace;**

```
echo str_replace("<br/>","",$st );
```

**Using strip_tags;**

```
echo strip_tags($st,"<p>");
```